# busybox wget wobzip download

Tags: html, input, wget, unzip

I'm using an openWRT router, and the flash size is very small. So I don't want to (can't) install any package for example unzip, full wget, curl.. etc
So I have a problem with wget which is built in busybox (not full wget). I want to unzip file with wobzip.org
Here is the input form of this site.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" action="/" method="post">
  <input name="Upload[url]" id="Upload_url" type="text" />
  <input id="ytUpload_file" type="hidden" value="" name="Upload[file]" />
  <input name="Upload[file]" id="Upload_file" type="file" >
  <input name="Upload[password]" id="Upload_password" type="text" />
  <input id="upload_submit" type="submit" name="yt0" value="Uncompress" />
  <input id="upload_progressing" style="display:none" name="yt1" type="button" value="Uploading" />
</form>
```

And i tried some way but these didn't work. I defined url variables earlier perfectly.

```
wget -O /tmp/something "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url&Upload[file]=&Upload[password]=&yt0=Uncompress"

wget -O /tmp/something "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url&Upload[file]=&Upload[password]="

wget -O /tmp/something "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url&Upload[file]="

wget -O /tmp/something "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url&Upload[file]="

wget -O /tmp/subtitle "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url"

wget -O /tmp/subtitle "http://wobzip.org/?Upload[url]=$url&Upload[password]="
```

So I tried all variations of the inputs. But it didn't work. 
Is it possible to do this without install any packages.

Comment: (1) The point of an input form is to __upload__ something.  As far as I can tell, you want to __download__ a file. (2) If you want to download a zipped file to your router but you can't unzip it there, download it to your computer, unzip it, upload the unzipped file somewhere (Dropbox, Google Drive, whatever), and download it to your router from there.

Comment: The input form support to unzip an url.I want to do it a script which run on transmission complete its already download fan-art, poster, etc... But I want to download subtitle also so this is the whole story. I can copy everything to the router by ftp, samba, SCP, SFTP but it's not automatized. So i want to download it automatically. I tried tar/gzip but it's not support the .zip file which i can download subscene or other subtitle page.